# C# Read Outlook contacts. What's the fastest way?

Tags: c#, outlook, com

I'm developing a C# forms application, where at one step, I have to display (in a listbox) all the contacts from the default Outlook account, that have a Company specified.

I came up with the following function:

```
outlookContactsList = new List<OutlookContactData>();

Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Items OutlookItems;
Outlook.Items FilteredOutlookItems;
Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder_Contacts;

Folder_Contacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
OutlookItems = Folder_Contacts.Items;

String CompanyMatch = "[CompanyName] <> ''";
FilteredOutlookItems = OutlookItems.Restrict(CompanyMatch);

var contactlist = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
foreach (Object _obj in FilteredOutlookItems)
{
    if (_obj is Outlook.ContactItem)
    {
        Outlook.ContactItem contact = (Outlook.ContactItem)_obj;
        if (contact != null)
        {
            if (contact.CompanyName != null && contact.CompanyName != string.Empty && contact.CompanyName != " ")
            {
                    OutlookContactData ocd = new OutlookContactData();

                    if (contact.FullName != null && contact.FullName != string.Empty)
                    {
                        ocd.DisplayMember = contact.CompanyName + " - " + contact.FullName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ocd.DisplayMember = contact.CompanyName;
                    }
                    ocd.ContactID = contact.EntryID;

                    outlookContactsList.Add(ocd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It takes a couple of seconds to read up a contact list of couple hundred entries... Any ways to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAPIFolder.GetTable` - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860692.aspx